# Create c++ program that can display 2 dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is the problem.

I know the basic like `int number[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};` 
but I cant increment it like what is needed

[image]

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){

    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int x;

    for (x = 0; x < 9; x++)
    {
        std::cout<<array[x]<<"\t"<<array[x]<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I feel someone has homework to do.

Comment: @sebap123 indeed But I don't know how to increment the value inside an array.

Comment: Firstly, create a 2 dimensional array to display. Then, elements in arrays are modifiable just as usual variables like `array[x] *= 2;`

Comment: You're not using a 2 dimensional array as the question requires. Don't use a 1 dimensional array and calculate the 2nd column's output from that. Use a pre-computed 2 dimensional array and output both columns from it directly. For each column use a for loop with an increment of 1 and 2 respectively to set the values of the elements. Do not multiply the first by 2 as others have suggested; that is not what the question wants.

Comment: @JBentley but how can I make a pre-computed 2 dimensional array?

Comment: I just told you how. Make a two dimensional array, then use for loops (one with a +1 increment and one with a +2) increment to set the elements representing each column.

Comment: I would recommend a quick trip to your teacher/professor/lab aid.  You should seek their help and advice often; you'll become a better student and programmer for it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply multiply array[x] by 2 and get the answer.

```
std::cout << "Number\tIncrement By 2"
    << endl << "------\t--------------" << endl;
for (x = 0; x < 9; x++)
{
    std::cout << array[x] << "\t" << array[x]*2 << std::endl;
}
```

This is a very basic solution otherwise you can store this data as well in a 2d array or a single array as well.